# SQL Statement issues (Not IN)

Tags: sql, oracle

Working through a uni assignment (down to the deadline), Can't figure out how/why im mis-using the NOT IN function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT P1.TITLE, P1.PANUM, D1.POSTCODE
FROM PAPER P1
INNER JOIN AUTHOR A1 ON A1.PANUM = P1.PANUM
INNER JOIN ACADEMIC A2 ON A2.ACNUM = A1.ACNUM
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D1 ON D1.DEPTNUM = A2.DEPTNUM
WHERE P1.PANUM NOT IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT P1.TITLE, P1.PANUM, D1.POSTCODE
    FROM PAPER P1
    INNER JOIN AUTHOR A1 ON A1.PANUM = P1.PANUM
    INNER JOIN ACADEMIC A2 ON A2.ACNUM = A1.ACNUM
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D1 ON D1.DEPTNUM = A2.DEPTNUM
    WHERE D1.POSTCODE LIKE '4%'
)
ORDER BY P1.PANUM;
```

The intention is to create a list of P1.TITLE that has no authors from a postcode starting in 4.

I'm getting a ORA-00913: Too Many Values error, and can't quite wrap my head around why.

Comment: maybe you want not exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to select one column on  inner subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT P1.TITLE, P1.PANUM, D1.POSTCODE
FROM PAPER P1
INNER JOIN AUTHOR A1 ON A1.PANUM = P1.PANUM
INNER JOIN ACADEMIC A2 ON A2.ACNUM = A1.ACNUM
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D1 ON D1.DEPTNUM = A2.DEPTNUM
WHERE P1.PANUM NOT IN(
    SELECT  P1.PANUM
    FROM PAPER P1
    INNER JOIN AUTHOR A1 ON A1.PANUM = P1.PANUM
    INNER JOIN ACADEMIC A2 ON A2.ACNUM = A1.ACNUM
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D1 ON D1.DEPTNUM = A2.DEPTNUM
    WHERE D1.POSTCODE LIKE '4%'
)
ORDER BY P1.PANUM;
```

Comment: @MarkBrealey: make sure the sub-query does not return any NULL values

Answer (score 1):

Just focusing on your problem:

> The intention is to create a list of P1.TITLE that has no authors from
>   a postcode starting in 4.

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT TITLE, PANUM
FROM PAPER
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM AUTHOR
    INNER JOIN ACADEMIC ON AUTHOR.ACNUM = ACADEMIC.ACNUM
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT ON ACADEMIC.DEPTNUM = DEPARTMENT.DEPTNUM
    WHERE AUTHOR.PANUM = PAPER.PANUM
    AND DEPARTMENT.POSTCODE LIKE '4%'
)
ORDER BY PANUM
```

Comment: The issue i have with your revision is some Papers have multiple authors from Different states, so the record of the paper remains in the results if there are Authors from other states.

Answer (score 0):

When you use IN and NOT IN keyword, that means only one parameters (or column) should be inside it.